# Which package do I need to load to use \todo[inline]

Tags: packages

I was recommended the tool `\todo[inline]` to comment on what still needs to be done.

Which package do I need to load to use it?

When I googled it, I never found a complete document which declared the packages used, but rather github commits and such.

To avoid package conflicts, I should add which packages I already use in the relevant document:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
```

Comment: The `luatodonotes` package has a `\todo[inline]{...}` command, I do not know if you mean this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had first mistakenly labelled the command `\todoinline` (no parenthesis); correct is: `\todo[inline]`

Schrödinger's Cat suggested `luatodonotes`, which is required if you use LuaLaTex. Since I use PDFLaTex, the required package is `todonotes`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `\usepackage{todonotes}` : https://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes

Comment: yep. I also found that out after Schrödinger's Cat's suggestion. I already answered my own question, but maybe it's not visible publicly because I don't have enough reputation? I don't know

Comment: I can now see your answer. Hopefully you can use todo notes with either pdf or Lua Latex :)

Comment: yep, it works :)